# Symfony Composer install without clearing cache

Tags: php, symfony, caching, installation, composer-php

We are using a different cache dir to the default one and are using build agents for deployment. We run the composer install on the build agent where the cache dir doesn't exist, and then rsync it over to the web servers where we then run the command to clear and warm up the cache (all done from a Bamboo deployment).

Of course an error comes back in the logs as it can't create the cache dir when the composer install runs on the agent (and we don't want it to as we do this after).

Is there any way that when I run the composer install I can get it to skip the cache clear? I can't see it as a parameter option for composer.

Comment: Look at `post-install-cmd` in `composer.json`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As much as others say it doesn't, Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler‌​::installAssets will do a cache clear if required which will cause issues if you can not write to cache (I do this once rsynced from build agent onto live server).

The only way I can find at the moment to get around this is to remove the 2 lines from composer.json:

```
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
```

and then once you are on the server that has your cache dir available, run the following 2 commands (by this stage you should have already done your composer install/update):

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
php bin/console assets:install --env=prod
```

The assets:install may or may not be needed depending on the vendor bundles installed. Anything that uses the "public" folder to store resources will need this so that the symbolic links are set up correctly for /web/bundles/bundleName. I also do an assetic dump after this.

By doing this you can now do the long parts (git clone and composer install) on a separate server or in a different directory and then rsync it across to where you want it to go. Then you just refresh and warm up the cache and do the final config of assets/assetic (or anything you are doing that requires cache) with minimal down time or any issues of your site going down if something goes wrong half way through deployment.

Answer (score 6):

All you need is to remove following line:

```
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
```

from `post-install-cmd` and/or `post-update-cmd` section in your `composer.json` file.

Assuming you're build agent is doing `install`, and not `update`, it may be useful, to keep this line in `post-update-cmd` section for development work.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets" does the cache clear as well (and I can't get rid of this line).

Comment: I don't think that's true. I'm looking at `AssetsInstallCommand` source code right now and I don't see anything related to cache or clearing anything.

Comment: By the way, I think that cache directory should exist in project as it is **not** ignored by `.gitignore` file by default so it's versioned.

Comment: I get an error to say that line is trying to clear the cache once I remove the line you suggested. As far as the cache dir goes, it exists, but just not on the build agent. It exists on the server outside the web root dir. We want to  get all vendor files, set up src files etc and then send it to the live server to do the cache refresh.

Comment: Works well.  In case my way of applying it can help someone : I added this to my Jenkins scriptI : `sed -i '/.*"Sensio\\\\Bundle\\\\DistributionBundle\\\\Composer\\\\ScriptHandler::clearCache.*",/d' /var/www/myProject/composer.json` This let me fix at deployement time without needing access to the repo.

Comment: you are removing the question instead of giving an answer